# Add a new row to DataGrid at runtime (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid and fill it when window loaded, like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var list = DbService.GetStuffsFull();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

and when i try to add a new row at run-time by this code:

```
Stuff item = new Stuff();
dataGrid.Items.Add(item);
```

I get this error:

> Operation is not valid while
>   ItemsSource is in use. Access and
>   modify elements with
>   ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

how can I add a new row at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify items in `Items` collection if you provided it as `ItemsSource`. You should either add item to your `list` (with `INotifyCollectionChanged` implemented or you should initially populated `Items` property via `Add` method.

The error description is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: Note that in most cases, the best way to get `INotifyCollectionChanged` is to use `ObservableCollection;.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this: 
    var row = dataGrid.NewRow();

```
    dataGrid.Rows.Add(row);
    row["column1"] = "data1";  
    row["column2"] = "data2";
    row["column3"] = "data3";

InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Do you really propose interacting with `dataGrid` before calling `InitializeComponent`?